# Venn diagram in python, one subset containing the other two

Tags: matplotlib-venn

I'm using matplotlib-venn to create a Venn diagram that contains three subsets, one of which contains the other two (and these other two intersect each other).

```
venn3(subsets=(17, 29, 40, 154, 17, 29, 40), set_labels = ('A', 'B','C'), ax=axes)
```

C contains both A and B, and I'd like to selectively show only some of the 
 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's not possible to do what is asked in the question using the matplotlib-venn package.